# Pig Latin using first value in a file in every row

Tags: apache-pig

I have a high number of files, all in the same structure. In the first line of every file is a key (in this example the key of a movie), followed by the records of user-id, rating and date.

Example file 1:

```
1:  
1488844,3,2005-09-06  
822109,5,2005-05-13  
885013,4,2005-10-19
```

Example file 2:

```
2:  
2059652,4,2005-09-05  
1666394,3,2005-04-19  
1759415,4,2005-04-22  
1959936,5,2005-11-21
```

In order to process the data in pig and get the highest ratings and average rating per movie or year, I would need something like this:

```
1,1488844,3,2005-09-06  
1,822109,5,2005-05-13  
1,885013,4,2005-10-19  
2,2059652,4,2005-09-05  
2,1666394,3,2005-04-19  
2,1759415,4,2005-04-22  
2,1959936,5,2005-11-21
```

How can I manage this?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
inputs = LOAD 'input_path/*' using PigStorage('-tagsource');
grouped = GROUP inputs by $0;
processed = FOREACH grouped {
    key_row = FILTER inputs BY [regexp expression for the key row, or some simple string expression];
    without_key_row = FILTER input BY [the opposite expression];
    GENERATE
        (chararray)key_row,
        FLATTEN(without_key_row);
}
```

Comment: +1. It is worthwhile to note that if the `FILTER` for `key_row` returns anything other than a single line then the scalar type cast in  the `GENERATE` will fail. So for less distinct key rows the expression to determine it should be carefully chosen.